# Debugging a System.FormatException

Tags: c#, debugging, exception, runtime-error

"Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list."
("Der Index, basierend auf 0 (null), muss größer als oder gleich Null sein, und kleiner als die Größe der Argumentenliste.")

when executing the line:

```
search.Filter = string.Format(filter,filterparams);
```

where, at runtime, `filter` contains `"(sAMAccountName={0})(sAMAccountName={1})"` and `filterparams` is a StringList with the two member strings "Testuser" and "Vertrieb".

What exactly is the error message trying to tell me?

Comment: Use `search.Filter = string.Format(filter,filterparams.ToArray());`, or `search.Filter = string.Format(filter,filterparams[0], filterparams[1]);`

Comment: Thx, that works. The second is limited to two params - but in production mine could go into two-digit numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error says that there are more tokens in the format string than in the argument list. The second parameter of String.Format is an array of objects (from MSDN):

```
public static string Format(
    string format,
    params object[] args
)
```

The StringList is not implicitly converted to an array of objects so that String.Format interprets the StringList as one argument - hence the error.

Comment: To expand on that: Each item of the filter Array must be fed directly to the format function. Simply call filterparams.ToArray()

Comment: @Christian Sauer: Thanks for the additional info.